# Why does docsvlist not work in an environment?

Tags: tables, environments, etoolbox

In an experiment to postprocess a table I encountered a discrepancy 
concerning docsvlist. The same code works (shows a table with a  b...) when called directly in the document, but not (shows a table with Γ  Γ...) when it is embedded in the enddef of an environment.

I hardly dare to ask whether this is a bug, as TeX has so many surprises
for the uninitiated. So, what should I do to make it work inside the enddef.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,ifthen,etoolbox}
\newcounter{Nr}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Test}{s O{t}}{%
}{%
  \setcounter{Nr}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{\\\setcounter{Nr}{0}}{}%
    \stepcounter{Nr}%
    #1
    \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{}{&}%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}%
    \docsvlist{a,b,c,d,e,f,}
  \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
%
\begin{Test}
\end{Test}
\hspace{1cm}
\setcounter{Nr}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{\\\setcounter{Nr}{0}}{}%
    \stepcounter{Nr}%
    #1%
    \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{}{&}%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}%
    \docsvlist{a,b,c,d,e,f,}%
  \end{tabular}%
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work in the environment, but you have to use `##1`, i.e. the argument of `\do`, and not `#1`, which is the 1st argument of the `test` enviroment, meaning the `starred` one here, which will 'always' print as Γ then.

Defining commands within other macros needs a doubling of the `#` character for accessing the 'local' argument, i.e. `##1`, `##2` etc. If this inner macro has further macro definitions, `##1` becomes `####1` etc. for the innermost macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse,ifthen,etoolbox}
\newcounter{Nr}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Test}{s O{t}}{%
}{%
  \setcounter{Nr}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{\\\setcounter{Nr}{0}}{}%
    \stepcounter{Nr}%
    ##1%
    \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{}{&}%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}%
    \docsvlist{a,b,c,d,e,f,}
  \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
%
\begin{Test}
\end{Test}
\hspace{1cm}
\setcounter{Nr}{0}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{\\\setcounter{Nr}{0}}{}%
  \stepcounter{Nr}%
  #1%
  \ifnumequal{\value{Nr}}{2}{}{&}%
}%
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
  \docsvlist{a,b,c,d,e,f,}%
\end{tabular}%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Shorter version without `ifthen` package

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}
\newcounter{Nr}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Test}{s O{t}}{%
}{%
  \setcounter{Nr}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \ifnum2=\value{Nr}\relax%
    \\\setcounter{Nr}{0}%
    \fi
    \stepcounter{Nr}%
    ##1%
    \ifnum2=\value{Nr}\relax%
    \else \unexpanded{&} \fi
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}%
    \docsvlist{a,b,c,d,e,f,}
  \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
%
\begin{Test}
\end{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jack: You're welcome. Happy TeXing